# Mass email with personalized content

Tags: email, merge, office365, office-automation, mass-emails

I know it's not 100% related to coding, but there is plenty of knowledgeable folks here, someone may know the answer.
I need to send a mass email (270 recipients) and each email needs to contain a pull from Excel sheet, containing data related to people that report to each recipient. So one recipient would get an email with 3-4 people, while the other recipient would get email with 10-15 different data points (like name, DOB, etc.)

I tried mail merge but it just sends multiple emails with separated data points for each person to each recipient (each recipient gets 10-15 emails related to 10-15 different people).

If there is a function in MS Office environment - what's it called? If there is resource (YT clip, etc.) would you have a link?

Many, many thanks!

Comment: Have you looked on here for similar solutions or code you could tweak?

Comment: I did. They are either to sophisticated (this can't be coding solution, as people I work with will not be able to follow) or the solutions only give one excel row feed per email. I need to find a way to feed multiple rows of excel data into each personalized email I mass send.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate Outlook from Excel, see [Automating Outlook from Other Office Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/automating-outlook-from-other-office-applications) for more information. With Outlook object model you may configure whatever you need - reading the range of different cells in Excel and paste that information into the message body according to your needs.